# Baseline Profiles - Problem Generating Release BaselineProfile

Tags: android, performance, baseline-profile

I am trying to implement the **Baseline profiles**([official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/baselineprofiles)) for my app. Following the steps indicated in this video([Improving Performance with Baseline Profiles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWdDzXgrkmg&ab_channel=AndroidDevelopers)) if I use the ***DebugBuildVariant*** I am able to create the *baseline-prof.txt* file to improve the startup time . But when I try to create the baseline-prof file for release I have this exception:

```
./gradlew :macrobenchmark:pixel2Api31BenchmarkAndroidTest -P android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.BaselineProfileGenerator
```

```
com.example.BaselineProfileGenerator > generate[pixel2Api31] FAILED
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to confirm activity launch completion [] Please report a bug with the output of `adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo com.leinardi.forlago framestats`
                at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkScope.startActivityImpl(MacrobenchmarkScope.kt:179)
Tests on pixel2Api31 failed: There was 1 failure(s).
```

This is how it looks like our *BaselineProfileGenerator*:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalBaselineProfilesApi::class)
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class BaselineProfileGenerator {
    @get:Rule
    val rule = BaselineProfileRule()

    @Test
    fun generate() {
        rule.collectBaselineProfile("com.leinardi.forlago") {
            pressHome()
            startActivityAndWait()
        }
    }
}
```

If I configure the benchmark for *Debug* it works well:

```
benchmark {
    initWith buildTypes.debug
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
    debuggable false
    proguardFiles('benchmark-rules.pro')
}
```

But configuring it for *Release*, benchmark throws the previous exception when you try to generate it.

```
benchmark {
    initWith buildTypes.release
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    matchingFallbacks = ['release']
    debuggable false
    proguardFiles('benchmark-rules.pro')
}
```

**Component used:** Baseline Profiles

**Version used:** AGP=7.3.0-rc01, uiautomator=2.2.0 & benchmark-macro-junit4=1.1.0

**Devices/Android versions reproduced on:**

```
testOptions {
        managedDevices {
            devices {
                pixel2Api31(com.android.build.api.dsl.ManagedVirtualDevice) {
                    device = "Pixel 2"
                    apiLevel = 31
                    systemImageSource = "aosp"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Reported on Google Issue tracker:** [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243640033)

**Sample project to trigger the issue:** https://github.com/leinardi/Forlago/tree/baseline-profiles

Comment: were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you used `SplashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition` in your activity? If yes, commenting out the line could help.
You can disable it if the current build-type is `benchmark`.

```kotlin
if (!BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.contains("benchmark")) {
    splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the sample code and it looks like the problem is not within the library, but within the sample project itself.

You get exception during app launch, because `FirebaseCrashlytics` is not initialized in release build type

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.leinardi.forlago, PID: 4684
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.leinardi.forlago. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:47)
at com.leinardi.forlago.library.logging.CrashlyticsTree.log(CrashlyticsTree.kt:15)
at timber.log.Timber$Tree.prepareLog(Timber.kt:97)
at timber.log.Timber$Tree.e(Timber.kt:3)
at timber.log.Timber$Forest.e(Timber.kt:6)
at com.leinardi.forlago.library.android.interactor.android.GetAppUpdateInfoInteractor$invoke$2.invokeSuspend(GetAppUpdateInfoInteractor.kt:181)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:9)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:99)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:12)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:3)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:82)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@c988cf0, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

Once I commented out `CrashlyticsTree`, the profile is generated properly.

Comment: Thanks @mlykotom! Yep, the problem was what you said, `FirebaseCrashlytics` was not initialized in release.

Comment: You can accept the answer in that case, so it's not popping up as unanswered. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Baseline Profile generation requires a non-obfuscated build. [Check here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/baselineprofiles/create-baselineprofile)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `pressHome()` in your profileBlock field, then remove it. Use only startActivityAndWait. If you are using custom ui tests, then use startActivityAndWait with pressHome for generate profile file properly :)

Comment: I actually found that adding a delay to the `pressHome()` call, i.e. `pressHome(delayDurationMs = 1000)`, is a better approach than outright removing the `pressHome()` call.